# Changes should be reflect in only tablet devices

Tags: android-layout, css, tablet, media-queries, android

I have applied body-background color(ex:blue) to my page. But when i open this page in tablets, mobile devices the color should change to orange color. when i resize my pc browser window the colors wont be change. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the width by changing the CSS tag; but that changes across all devices.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1440px) {
```

To determine if its a tablet or what device the user is using specifically you can use Javascript to determine the device. Then load CSS accordingly.

You can look at the code here; [link]http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ipad[/link]

The problem with that is there is thousands of devices out there. So you'll have to check for each device.

```
// For use within normal web clients 
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;

// For use within iPad developer UIWebView
// Thanks to Andrew Hedges!
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
var isiPad = /iPad/i.test(ua) || /iPhone OS 3_1_2/i.test(ua) || /iPhone OS 3_2_2/i.test(ua);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted a CSS3 Media Query; as posted below?

```
/*Common Tablet Width*/
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    body{
       background-color:blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: if the tablet is more than 1024px like 1280, 1440... something like that how will we define?